# multiple targets with the same product name, same bundle id, is it possible?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

long story short, I have a xcode (cocoa) project, and I have two targets added to this proj. One is for the sandboxed version and the other one is the non-sandboxed version. (for details please read: [one project, two versions? (sandboxed and nonsandboxed version)? any easy way to maintain the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682384/one-project-two-versions-sandboxed-and-nonsandboxed-version-any-easy-way-to))

however I'm not sure if I should, or shouldn't keep the same product name and same bundle id, as I don't know what's the pros and cons of doing so.

These two targets are pretty much the same, except that for the sandboxed version, I have to enable sandbox and added the entitlements, while the non-sandboxed one doesn't have such limitation, also I can add the sparkle framework to it so that it auto updates the app if necessary.

So my reason of having the same product name and same bundle id is, they are mostly identical and I really don't want to rename one of the product name to My Product - sandboxed version, or My product - non sandboxed version. Also they are both full version, so I can't named one product as Full and the other one as Lite.

So my question is, for these 2 targets if I use the same product name and same bundle id will I cause any problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could change the Build Products Path under Build Settings for each target to a unique subdirectory ("AppStore" vs. "Self-Distro" or whatever).